# How to understand the induced complex structure of a quotient space?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I saw a proposition in page 60-61 in [https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/Riemann.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eteleman/math/Riemann.pdf)

> Proposition: $\mathfrak{H} / S L(2, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{C}$, and the bijection is implemented by the (holomorphic) elliptic modular function $J$,
> $$
> J(\tau)=\frac{g_{2}^{3}}{g_{2}^{3}-27 g_{3}^{2}},
> $$
> ......

where $\mathfrak{H}=\{z|Im(z)>0\}$.

I am confused about the statement of this proposition, since I do not understand why $\mathfrak{H} / S L(2, \mathbb{Z})$  is a Riemann surface. I only know that if a group $G$ acts on a Riemann surface $X$ with no fixed point (i.e. $gx\ne x$ for any $1\ne g\in G$ and $x\in X$), then the quotient space $X/G$ has a induced complex structure. However, the action of $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathfrak{H}$, which is $z\mapsto-\frac{1}{z}$, has a fixed point $i$.

A similar example is $\mathbb{C}/\{\pm 1\}$, which seems like a cone. Does it have an induced complex structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Riemann surface $\Gamma\backslash U$ for some subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$ on which a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206718/riemann-surface-gamma-backslash-u-for-some-subset-u-of-mathbbc-on-whic). See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438151/finite-group-quotient-of-complex-manifolds/3499792#3499792) for the case of higher-dimensional complex manifolds.

Comment: The keyword here is [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity). In the case of $\mathbb C / \{\pm 1\}$, letting $[0] \in \mathbb C / \{\pm 1\}$ be the image of $0$ under the quotient map $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C / \{\pm 1\}$, one may regard $[0]$ as a removable singularity.

Comment: I previously thought that only local homeomorphism permits one to push out the chart of a complex manifold. Now I understand that if we have a complex manifold X and a topological manifold Y, and a map from X to Y, and Y admits a complex structure such that f is holomorphic, then we can call it the induced complex structure. Is my understanding correct? @Moishe Kohan

Comment: @qdmj: I am not sure about that degree of generality, but in the context of quotients by properly discontinuous group actions, then yes.